# Inverse of polynomial over $\mathbb F_3$ finite field, quotient space

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, extension-field

A question about quotient spaces, something I do not fully understand yet, and can use some help.

$A = \mathbb F_3[x]$, $P = x^3-x+2\in A$

1) Show that $P$ is irreducible (I did it, it has no roots in $\mathbb F_3$).

2) Find the inverse of $x^2+P$ in $A/P$.

My problem is that I don't know what are the elements of $A/P$. I don't know what that is.

If I understand right, $x^2+P$ is the equivalence class of $x^2$ in $A/P$, but what now?

Comment: Thsi fits more to extensions of fields, quotient rings and stuff, and **not** quotient spaces. Have you studied extensions of fields, Galois Theory or stuff?

Comment: I'm not native to speaking english so I have some difficulties with the terminology, sorry if I have been misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of $A/P$ are of the form $f(x) + P$, where $f(x) \in A$. However, there is one important simplification : Euclidean division gives you polynomials $t, r \in A$ such that
$$
f = tP + r, \text{ and } \deg(r) < 3
$$
Now $f + P = r + P$, and so you can assume that all elements of $A/P$ are of the form
$$
(ax^2 + bx + c) + P
$$
So you are now trying to find a polynomial of this form such that
$$
(x^2 + P)(ax^2 + bx + c + P) = 1 + P
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow ax^4 + bx^3 +cx^2 - 1 \in P
$$
Now use the fact that $x^3 + P =  x-2+P$, and so this implies
$$
ax(x-2) + b(x-2) + cx^2 - 1 \in P
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow (a+c)x^2 + (b-2a)x + (-1-2b) \in P
$$
But this is a polynomial of degree $<3$, and there is no such polynomial in $P$ other than the zero polynomial (why?). Hence
$$
a+c = 0, \qquad b-2a = 0, \qquad \text{ and } -1-2b = 0
$$
Now use the fact that $2 \equiv -1$ in $\mathbb F_3$ to solve these equations.

Comment: I lost you near the end, why $x^3+P = x-2+P$?

Comment: Ok, I understand that. I do. Everything you've done so far, I understood. But how does this help me find the inverse of $x^2$ in $A/P$? I agree with you that I need to find a polynomial $g$ $deg(g)<3$ such that $(x^2+P)(g+P) = 1+P$, but how does $x^3+P=x-2+P$ help me?

Comment: There is no such polynomial in $P$ because $deg(\alpha P)=3$ for all $\alpha$ except $\alpha=0$ and $0*P=0$

Comment: Is the answer $2x^2+x+1$?

Comment: yeah I did, c=1 :) Is the answer correct? Is my reasoning for "this is a polynomial of degree <3, and there is no such polynomial in P other than the zero polynomial (why?)." correct?

Comment: No. The polynomials in $P$ are of the form $\{f(x)(x^3-x+2)\}$ and hence they all have degree at least 3 (if not more)

Comment: but what if that $f(x)=0$? You will get a polynomial that is only zeroes. It's in P. and its degree is less than 3

Comment: Yes, but zero is the only one such polynomial.

Comment: I know...That's what I said :) Thank you very much prahlad I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to find two polynomials S and T in $F_3[x]$ such that $S(x^3-x+2)+x^2T=1$.

What appens to this equality in $A/P$?

Comment: in $A/P$ since that the equivalence class of $P$ is 0, it will turn to: equivalence class of $x^2$ times the equivalence class of $T$ equals equivalence class of 1. this reminds me of gcd and euclids algorithm, is there a connection?

Comment: Yes, there is. In general you can use the euclids algorthm  to solve a diophantine equation in a UFD ring and then reduce the Bezout equality to obtain a solution in the quotient...

Comment: I have no idea what you just said haha