# Show that the field $L = \mathbb F_3[X]/\langle X^5 - X + 1\rangle$ consists of $243$ elements and that $[X][f] = [1]$ for some $[f] \in L$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

> Show that the field $L = \mathbb F_3[X]/\langle X^5 - X + 1\rangle$ consists of $243$ elements and that $[X][f] = [1]$ for some $[f] \in L$.

I know that $L$ is a ring, so it is also a group with respect to $+$. However I how no idea how to calculate the size of $L$ or finding $[f]$ such that $[X][f] = [1]$ other than by brute-force, which is a terrible approach to solving a problem of this size.

Also I've proven that $\langle X^5 - X + 1\rangle$ is a maximal ideal and that $X^5 - X + 1$ is irreducible.

Could someone give me a hint or help to fit the "loose ends" here ?

Comment: Some hints: First of all, it helps to consider $L$ as an $\mathbb F_3$-vectorspace, and note that $243 = 3^5$. Now, if $K$ is a finite field with $k$ elements, an $n$-dimemsional $K$-vectorspace has $k^n$ elements... To show that $L$ is a field, you should be able to use the following well-known theorem: Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ a maximal ideal. Then $R/I$ is a field.

Comment: Hint:
$$
X(X^4-1)=X^5-X\equiv-1\pmod{X^5-X+1}.
$$

Comment: Your first question is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/577095/11619). Should we call this a duplicate?

Comment: [An earlier thread related to your first question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/567022/11619). I was expecting to find another instance of "find the inverse" problem sooner, but I had to dig for it.

Comment: All right I've calculated that $[X][-X^4+1]=[1]$.

Comment: I've a lemma telling me:
Let $F$ be a finite field. Then $|F|=p^n$, where $p$ is a prime number, $n \ge 1$ and there exists an irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb F_p[X]$ of degree $n$ such that $F \cong F_p[X]/ \langle f \rangle$. Now I just need to find a finite field of order $243$ ? Can you help me ?

Comment: Do you also have a theorem saying that a commutative ring moded by a maximal ideal gives you a field? BTW. You found the correct inverse of the coset $[X]$. Well done!

Comment: Yes, but I need to know this field is finite. My idea is: There is $3^5 = 243$ different remainders modulo $X^5 - X + 1$. Let $[x] \in F_3[X]/\langle X^5 - X + 1 \rangle$ and $r = x \mod X^5 - X + 1$. Then $[x] = [r]$ because $x - r \in F_3[X]/\langle X^5 - X + 1 \rangle$. $[x] \in F_3[X]/\langle X^5 - X + 1 \rangle$ is equal to $[x \mod X^5 - X + 1]$, and no remainder class is empty since the remainders itself map to these classes. I can conclude that the remainders have $\ge \deg 4$ because the polynomial $X^5 - X + 1$ is monic.